# C# Using GetProcessIoCounters to read total Disk IO per second (near realtime)

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I've been Googling around and reading all sorts of posts, solutions, etc; but I cannot find or figure out how to achieve what I want exactly.

Long story short, I need to display total Disk IO Read + Write per second per process. For this purpose, I found GetProcessIoCounters() which should do the trick.

The issue is calculating the data and display it accordingly.

Definition is as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetProcessIoCounters(IntPtr hProcess, out IO_COUNTERS lpIoCounters);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct IO_COUNTERS
{
    public UInt64 ReadOperationCount;
    public UInt64 WriteOperationCount;
    public UInt64 OtherOperationCount;
    public UInt64 ReadTransferCount;
    public UInt64 WriteTransferCount;
    public UInt64 OtherTransferCount;
};
```

The data is retrieved and updated every second:

```
NativeFunctions.IO_COUNTERS lpIo = new NativeFunctions.IO_COUNTERS();

if (NativeFunctions.GetProcessIoCounters(ProcessList.ProcessData.Handle, out lpIo))
{
   ProcessList.io = lpIo;
}
```

After this operation I need to be able and say: "I/O Total: X/s". For this I was thinking of something along the lines:

```
ulong total = ProcessList.io.ReadOperationCount + ProcessList.io.WriteOperationCount + ProcessList.io.OtherOperationCount;
total *= 1024;
total /= 1;
```

But the result is not as intended. I need to see the total I/O currently used, not the total I/O since the process was started.

Can you please point in me the right direction ?

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You have misidentified your requirements. You do not need the current I/O readings. You need the total I/O within an interval. If you have a global accumulator you get the delta within an interval by subtracting the reading at t0 from the current, accumulated reading.

Comment: @IInspectable You have a point there. Can you post a sample for a C# noob here ?

Comment: @NorbertBoros, IInspectable means that you can call `GetProcessIoCounters` twice, use 2rd - 1st, and then divide by the elapsed time.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Can you post an answer ? Again, C# noob here. I only worked with C/C++ so far and I find C# "too managed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        IntPtr hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
        IO_COUNTERS lpIo1 = new IO_COUNTERS();
        IO_COUNTERS lpIo2 = new IO_COUNTERS();
        GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess, out lpIo1);

        int Sec = 1;
        Thread.Sleep(Sec * 1000);
        
        GetProcessIoCounters(hProcess, out lpIo2);

        ulong total1 = lpIo1.ReadOperationCount + lpIo1.WriteOperationCount + lpIo1.OtherOperationCount;
        ulong total2 = lpIo2.ReadOperationCount + lpIo2.WriteOperationCount + lpIo2.OtherOperationCount;
        ulong total = (total2 - total1) / Convert.ToUInt64(Sec);
```

`Sec` is the interval time between two `GetProcessIoCounters`. I use `Thread.Sleep(Sec * 1000)` to simulate the passage of `Sec` seconds.